# Xampp Virtual Host Apache '403 Access Forbidden' AH00132 / AH00529

Tags: macos, apache, xampp, macos-ventura

I've been having issues with Xampp and virtual hosts under Ventura 13.6.5 (Intel Mini).

Xampp (v8.2.4-0) works perfectly fine with the default `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` directory and any website under this works. However i'm wanting to add a virtual host for an additional 'website' pointing to a directory under my user `~/Documents` directory.

So i've enabled the vhost.conf file and added -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
    <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.test
    DocumentRoot "/Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/test/public_html"
    <Directory "/Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/test/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The default Xampp `localhost` works fine, however `local.test` fails with a `AH00132: file permissions deny server access: /Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/test/public_html/index.html` error.

In terms of trying to fix it, i have tried -

- Made sure the entire `/Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/` directory is `chmod -R  DeltaSierra:staff`, which still results in a AH00132/403 error message.
- Have tried a `chown -R 777` on the `/Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/` directory, same result.
- Changed the Apache/httpd process (within httpd.conf) to run as `User DeltaSierra / Group staff`, again same result.
- Made sure the all the user/group ACL's (ie - user 'DeltaSierra', group 'staff' and 'everyone') on `/Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/` are set to `Read & Write` (and apply it to sub-directories etc), exactly the same.

Looking at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`, it seems it's permissions are set to `root:admin`. However, the ACL's on `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` seems to show a `system` user which doesn't appear to be on the machine.

So changing Apache/httpd back to run as the default daemon user and group, i tried to add the `system` user -

```
sudo chmod -R +a "system allow list,add_file,search,delete,add_subdirectory,delete_child,chown,file_inherit,directory_inherit" /Users/DeltaSierra/Documents/DevSites/
```

Which failed as the `system` user doesn't exist and returns a UUID not found type error. I tried adding the `daemon` user, which does exist and Apache returned the error -

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:54286] AH00529: /Users/DeltaSierra/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that /Users/DeltaSierra/' is executable
```

But that doesn't make particular sense and seems to suggest making the entire `/Users/DeltaSierra/` directory executable.

So i'm at a loss now and it seems unless websites are under `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`, Xampp (Apache) doesn't want to know.

I don't doubt i've missed something simple but, does anyone have any clue how to get Xampp to execute websites under a user owned directory/within `~/Documents`?

Really appreciate any help as i'm currently going around in circles.

P.s - the reason to try and get Xampp to load sites within `~/Documents`, is because my editors have to be elevated everytime i save to `/Applications` which is extremely annoying when editing large amounts of files.